# Проблема с тестированием сортировки массива int java

Tags: java, массивы, юнит-тесты

Я сделал метод сортировки для сортировки массива в порядке возрастания:

```
public class Sorting {
    public void sort(int[] array) {

        if (Objects.isNull(array)) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();

        } else {
            Arrays.sort(array);
            System.out.println(array);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a SortingTest class:

```
public class SortingTest {

    Sorting sorting = new Sorting();

    @Test
    public void testNullCase() {
        int [] expected = null;
int [] actual = null;
        assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);

}
}
```

и я тестирую и `testEmptyCase (), testSingleElementArrayCase (), public void testSortedArraysCase () и testOtherCases ().`
Я тестирую свою программу для сортировки массива, но для отказа методов ниже @test. Как правильно делать тест? Я хочу понять, что мне нужно делать в тесте. Спасибо за помощь.

```
@Test
    public void testNullCarelessSorting() {
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Result result = junit.run(NullCarelessSortingTestExtension.class);

        assertEquals(1, result.getFailureCount());
        assertEquals(5, result.getRunCount());

        Failure nullCaseFailure = null;
        
    }

@Test
    public void testLazySorting() {
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Result result = junit.run(LazySortingTestExtension.class);

        assertEquals(2, result.getFailureCount());
        assertEquals(5, result.getRunCount());

        Failure nullCaseFailure = null;
        Failure otherCasesFailure = null;
        
    }
@Test
    public void testTrickySorting() {
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Result result = junit.run(TrickySortingTestExtension.class);

        assertEquals(4, result.getFailureCount());
        assertEquals(5, result.getRunCount());

        Failure emptyCaseFailure = null;
        Failure singleCaseFailure = null;
        Failure sortedCaseFailure = null;
        Failure otherCasesFailure = null;
           
}
```

Comment: Скинь пожалуйста код к testOtherCases()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну сдвиг на один сделан правильно. На несколько - метод рабочий, но неэффективный, получается квадратичное время.

Есть такой хитрый приём - реверсировать (развернуть порядок) часть длиной shift, реверсировать оставшуюся часть, реверсировать весь массив в целом. Время будет линейное.

Реализация не должна быть трудной [на всякий случай здесь подсмотреть](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-array-rotation-continued-reversal-algorithm/)

Относительно greater challenge - можно сделать через рекурсию или через откусывание части массива и соединение кусков (но тут циклы будут неявно в использованных библиотечный процедурах вроде arraycopy или addAll)